# Tutorial to send data as JsonArray to MySQL in Android using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I've tried a couple days in g*ogle to find any good tutorial how to do.

But until now, I have not find yet.

I have a json in android :

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "nilai": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "nilai": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "nilai": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "nilai": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "nilai": "1"
  }
]
```

And the String is looped the `id` and `nilai` for five times, then I want to send this json to server when button pressed.

The database i want to store looks like :

```
|---|-----|
| ID|Nilai|
|---|-----|
| 1 |  1  |
| 2 |  1  |
|...| ... |
```

Any suggest or idea? *I do not mind if you help answer with a code that you have on your application, at least the code can help me*

> I could not try the code how to do, due to limited understanding of the android and php programming myself, but I can try the code when I have a reference or examples of similar cases

Answer (score 0):

use volley library with a php file in server.

Here is a helpful links:

[android developers volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

[Volley json  post tuturial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggest sir, but i have read the that tutor last time, and i dont know how it work with my project, because the tutor just insert a single row, and mine, i need to insert 5 data at once with button

Answer (score 0):

you want to send something like that [{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},{"id":"2","nilai":"1"},{"id":"3","nilai":"1"},{"id":"4","nilai":"1"},{"id":"5","nilai":"1"}]

what you can do is :

Java/Android

```
String jsonObjectString="{\"id\":1,\"nilai\":1}";
```

you can use a loop to make as much as you want:

```
ArrayList<String> yourList=new Arrayist<>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  yourList.add("{\"id\":"+(i+1)+",\"nilai\":1}");
}
```

then use Volley to send the ArrayList with POST:

```
String url = "url that handle the request";
    final Context currentContext = CompleteDataActivity.this;
    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // success handling code here
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // error handling code here
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            //Post parameter
            for(int i=0;i<yourList.size();i++)
            {
                param.put("jsonObject"+i, yourList.get(i));
            }

            return param;
        }
    };
    H.showLoadingDialog(currentContext);
    MyVolley.getRequestQueue().add(request);
```

use this code to get your list of JSONObject for .php

```
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
        {
            $var = "jsonObject".$i;
            $jsonObject=json_decode($_POST[$var]);
            $id = $jsonEtape->{'id'};
            $nilai = $jsonEtape->{'nilai'};
            $sql = "your query;";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        }
```

hope this helps